# node http server listen and on('open') event

Tags: javascript, node.js

This question is related to my previous one:

[node httpServer EADDRINUSE and next port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22262128/node-httpserver-eaddrinuse-and-next-port)

Currently, I do

```
var port = 8000;
HTTPserver
  .listen(port, function()
  {
    console.log('HTTP listening:' + port);
  })
  .on('error', function(err)
  {
    if (err.code === 'EADDRINUSE')
    {
      // port is currently in use
      console.log('server Open error:' + port);

      port++;
      HTTPserver
        .listen(port);
    }
  });
```

However, this code structure is hard to manage when things get complicated, and I perfer to write as follows:

```
var port = 8000;
HTTPserver
  .on('open', function()
  {
    console.log('HTTP listening:' + port);
  })
  .on('error', function(err)
  {
    if (err.code === 'EADDRINUSE')
    {
      // port is currently in use
      console.log('server Open error:' + port);

      port++;
      HTTPserver.listen(port);
    }
  });

HTTPserver.listen(port);
```

This appears more straightforwad to me, and actually easier to handle in complicated situations.

However, referring 
http://nodejs.org/api/http.html appears that an event 'open' does not exist.

Is there any corresponding event or it's not possible to write like this?

Thanks.

Comment: What are you expecting `.open()` to do?

Comment: Well, whatever. It's so common to have `open` event for socket things, and I don't know why node basic server does not have this.

Comment: I have no idea what you just said. "Whatever"?? You aren't even saying what you think `open` should do for a node server

Comment: Oh, you have suggested `open` method instead of `on('open')`, I have tried, but it says: `Object #<Server> has no method 'open'`, and actually, there's no such a method in the documentation.

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped. What are you expecting `.on("open"` to do

Comment: Please note your question does not solve my question, and off-topic.

Comment: ...How would a question answer your question?

Comment: I've had a valid answer corresponding to my question. Refer it and consider why your comments are off-topic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [listening](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_event_listening) event:

```
const port = 8000;
HTTPserver.on('listening', function() {
  console.log('HTTP listening:' + port);
})
```

Comment: Great. I missed this. Thanks!